# Distance outside shapely.Polygon

Tags: python, shapely

How do I establish the distance a point is from a polygon? If the point is within the polygon the result should be 0.

I'm guessing something like:

```
def distance_from(poly,point):
  if poly.contains(point): return 0 
  return poly.exterior.distance(point)
```

Comment: Why do you think something's wrong with your guess? Weird results, error messages, ...?

Comment: What class is `poly`? Does it have a `contains` method? What's the format of your`point` variable? This question raises many many more questions

Comment: @Andrew shapely.Polygon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to clarify things up a bit:

The instances which are passed to the `distance_from` function are made of the classes `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` and `shapely.geometry.point.Point` from the `shapely.geometry` module of the *Shapely Python package for computational geometry*. (For more info on shapely and geometric objects have a look in the manual : [Shapely Python Package](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#the-shapely-user-manual), [Geometric Objects](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#geometric-objects)).

The `distance` method of a geometric object returns the *minimum* float distance to another geometric object as described [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.distance) in the manual. The exterior of a polygon is an instance of `shapely.geometry.polygon.LinearRing` which makes up the boundary of a polygon (although it is not to be mixed up with the `boundary` attribute of a polygon which returns a `LineString`). So for the case above you don't need to to explicitly use `poly.exterior.distance(point)` because the minimum distance is the same for the whole polygon as it is for its boundary. They have exactly the same shape only a different geometry type.

It would be less error prone if you would just use `poly.distance(point)` because that way if the point of interest lies within the `interior` ([more info here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#spatial-data-model)) of the polygon it is directly clear that it contains it, so you do not need an explicit check and also the distance from a point within the `interior` to itself is then 0. It would be different if you would try to get the distance from the `exterior` (which, as explained above, is a `LinearRing`, i.e. a closed `LineString`) to a point which lies in the "inner" part. In this case you would get the minimum distance between the point in the "inner" part and the surrounding linear ring.

For further info about binary relationships (i.e between a geometric object and another, which covers `contains`, `within`, `touches` etc.) refer to [this](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#binary-predicates) part of the manual and for those interested in the underlying DE-9IM relationships (which are a way to clearly identify the way a geometric objects relates to another) refer to [this](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#de-9im-relationships) part.

Shapely is a python wrapper for the [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos) suite which itself is a C++ port of [JTS](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/). On the JTS page under the link *Feature sheet* more information can be found about how spatial relationships are checked and computed

Comment: Documentation: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.distance